# Input для ввода пароля

Tags: html, css, svg, input

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как сделать такой input  для ввода пароля

```html
<svg class="background" width="121" height="31" viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 121 31" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <g fill="none" stroke="gray">
    <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="15" />
    <circle cx="60" cy="15" r="15" />
    <circle cx="105" cy="15" r="15" />
  </g>
</svg>
<input type="text" class="pass" maxlength="3" value="123"/>
```

Comment: Взять 4 отдельных инпута, добавить `border-radius: 50%`, выравнивание текста по центру и в конце, при отправке на сервер, чтобы не отправлять 4 значения из этих инпутов, просто соеденить их в один 4-х значный код.

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 8):

Можно использовать `letter-spacing` и фон из кругов (`inline-svg` для демонстрации). При таком подходе нужно использовать моноширинный(!) шрифт. Было бы ещё хорошо ограничить количество вводимых символов через `js`.

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.pass{
  font-family:monospace;
  font-size:18px;
  letter-spacing:35px;
  padding:4px 10px;
  letter-spacing:35px;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  position:relative;
  background:none;
  width:170px;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0, 120px 0, 120px 100%,0 100%);
}
.background{
  position:absolute;
  width:120px;
  height:30px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="background" viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 121 31" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <g fill="none" stroke="gray">
    <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="15" />
    <circle cx="60" cy="15" r="15" />
    <circle cx="105" cy="15" r="15" />
  </g>
</svg>
<input type="text" class="pass" maxlength="3" value="123"/>
```

Answer (score -3):

сделал отдельными инпутами и объединил их через jquery.groupinputs.js

Comment: Пожалуйста, пишите более развёрнутые ответы. Например, приведите примеры кода, вёрстки и прочего - так ответ будет гораздо более полезен будущим посетителям страницы)

Comment: Сомнительное решение. Вводить неудобно, скорее всего.

Comment: Зачем для такой простой задачи подключать лишний плагин? ужасная практика